How to paste encryption password for rclone's "crypt"
I'm trying to restore my rclone configuration and I have the original randomly generated encryption password and salt for one of my remotes. However, when setting this up in rclone on Windows, I can't paste the password into the command prompt. I can probably manually type it but it's too long and I don't trust myself to not make mistakes.
I also read that the password stored in rclone.conf is an obfuscated version of the actual password so I don't know how else I'm going to get the password into rclone.

For anyone encountering this same issue, it turns out you CAN paste the password into command prompt, just copy it and then right click on the command prompt window. Nothing will show up but press enter anyway after you do this. Same with the salt. Apparently, it still pastes it even if you can't see anything.
